# Sorting a NameValueCollection by value in c#

Tags: c#, collections, multidimensional-array, sorting, namevaluecollection

I have a NameValueCollection and I would like to sort this on his value. Does anyone got some ideas how to do this easely?
I was thinking to wrap it into a SortedList or SortedDictionairy but I'm not sure how to get started.

Thijs

Comment: Why not just call [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) on your collection?

Comment: Can't you use SortedDictionary or SortedList instead? Than it would be pretty easy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-c-sharp-dictionary-by-value , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250281/c-sharp-how-to-sort-a-sorted-list-by-its-value-column

Comment: @Pieter , That's the post I was looking for but didn't found! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
var sorted = nvc.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: Ok, this seems easy but I don't realy understand how to make that into a Collection.. Could you extend your code a bit please?

Comment: @Thijs - `sorted` is a collection.

Comment: @Thijs - Is there a problem with my answer?

Comment: @Thijs - No, it doesn't. That's why I said use `LINQ`. You need to add a `using System.Linq;` directive to the file. The `OrderBy` extension method is defined there.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I'll use that :)

Comment: This isn't quite correct, since NameValueCollection does not contain KeyValuePair<,>.

Answer (score 1):

I think the complexity of the solution depends on whether you care about multiple values per key. If you only need to sort the first value per key, the following should return the sorted result as an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`:

```
var sorted = nvc.AllKeys.OrderBy(key => nvc[key])
                .Select(key => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, nvc[key]));
```

If you care about multiple values per key, you may have to split each value into a KeyValuePair before sorting them. Something like:

```
var sorted = nvc.AllKeys
                .SelectMany(key =>
                    nvc.GetValues(key)
                       .Select(val => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, val)))
                .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

### Examples:

Given:

```
var nvc = new NameValueCollection() {
    { "key1", "c" },
    { "key1", "a" },
    { "key2", "b" }
};
```

The first example should return the following `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`:

```
key2: b
key1: c,a
```

The second example should return the following `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`:

```
key1: a
key2: b
key1: c
```